# Why does the main part repaint in this case?

Tags: css, repaint

Here is a simple jsbin example: http://jsbin.com/gusaditako/edit?html,css,output

Can anyone explain why the main part is repainting when hovering over menu items? (enable Paint flashing from chrome devtools to make sure).

As I see the pseudo `:before` selector is to blame but can't figure out exactly why. If you delete the last `ul#menu li:hover:before` part it doesn't trigger the main part repaint anymore...

Code from the above jsbin:

HTML:

```
  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>  
  </div>

  <div id="main">Main part. Why does this repaint on menu hover?</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}

ul#menu li {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

ul#menu li:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

ul#menu li:hover:before {
  content: "";
  width: 4px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean by repaint?

Comment: @Kushtrim Please enable `Paint flashing` from chrome devtools and hover over on menu items... Green areas you will see are places the browser is repainting every time the hover event is triggered.

Comment: I'm using custom font and this causes some strange UI issues like the font is blinking on completely different areas of the website when hovering over menu items...

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess Chrome internally thinks it has to repaint the right part as you're inserting a new element which could possibly affect the main content. One quick fix would be to set the whole sidebar to `position:absolute;` if that's possible in your case.

```
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/lilusajufe/4/edit?html,css,output